# Installing android-sdk or adt-bundle on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu

So on my previous laptop I've installed the `android-sdk-linux` and `Eclipse` separately without the `adt-bundle`, without any issues whatsoever. Also, I installed it under my `home` directory.

Now that I have a new laptop (clean slate) to start with, I wanted to try and install the adt-bundle into the correct/conventional directory (which I understand is `/usr/local/`).

But after extracting the bundle into `/usr/local/` I get weird issues like `adb` not being an executable, etc. Opening Eclipse yields a lot of errors regarding the `SDK`, `ADT`, and `adb`.

What is the correct method of doing this? A step-by-step or otherwise comprehensive set of methods would be greatly appreciated.

Also, is there any reason why I should consider installing `android-sdk-linux` and `Eclipse` separately instead of using the `adt-bundle`?

Thanks in advance :). This will help me learn more about Linux filesystems and administrations a little bit too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the problem is in Linux filesystem permissions of your folder. In case of home directory the owner of the files is your user, in case of `/usr/local/` the owner is root. You should try to change the owner of the folder:

```
chown -R <owner_name>:<owner_group> <your_dir>
```

As for reasons to install sdk and Eclipse separately, I don't think that you'll find critical one. Using bundle it's easier to install everything to work with Android (I think that Eclipse in this case is already configured, however I do not know precisely because I've never used this approach).

Comment: Thanks for your info. As you can see it is an issue with my understanding of Linux filesystems :). About the second point, I might just install android-sdk and Eclipse separately without the adt-bundle. Do you know how people usually download and install Eclipse? Is it better to do it through Synaptic or download directly from the Eclipse website? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I use Ubuntu 10.04 so I download Eclipse because in the repository there is a very old version. In your case, if repository contains new version of Eclipse, of course it's better to install it using standard  way (through synaptic or using apt-get install). If you want to download Eclipse manually you can try to find in the Internet the instructions how to this.

Comment: Okay thanks. No I can install Eclipse either way just fine. Just looking to see which one's the best/conventional way. Again, thanks.